# Determine whether or not the following structure $(P,S,1)$ is a Peano System

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, natural-numbers, peano-axioms

First this is how the book define as a Peano System.

By a Peano System we mean a set $P$, a particular element $1$ in $P$, and a singulary operation $S$ on $P$ such that the following axioms are satisfied.

- (P1) $1$ is not the successor $S(x)$ of any object $x$ in $P$. In Symbols:
  $$(\forall x)(S(x) \neq 1)$$
- (P2) Different objects in $P$ have different successors. This can be formulated as follows:
  $$(\forall x)(\forall y)(x \neq y \Rightarrow S(x) \neq S(y))$$
- (P3) Principle of mathematical induction: Any subset of $P$ containing $1$ and closed under $S$ must be identical with $P$. This can be symbolically rendered as follows:
  $$(\forall B)([B \subseteq P \land 1 \in B \land (\forall x)(x \in B \Rightarrow S(x) \in B)] \Rightarrow P=B)$$

Such a Peano System will be denoted by the ordered triple (P,S,1): $P$ is called **underlying set**, $S$ the **successor operation**, and $1$ the **distinguished element**.

Now the question:

Determine wheter or not the following structure (P,S,1) are Peano Systems.

a. $P$ is the set of all integers greater than $9$, "$1$" stands for the integer $10$. $S(u)=u+1$ for any $u$ in $P$.

My atempt:

$\checkmark$ (P1): Its clear that for any $x$ in $P$ we have that $x>9$ thus $(\forall x)(x+1 \neq 10)$ holds true

$\checkmark$ (P2): For any $x$ and $y$ in $P$ we have that $x \neq y \Rightarrow x+1 \neq y+1$

? (P3):
**begin edit 1**

First I assume some subset $B$ of $P$, such $10 \in B$ and $B$ is closed under $S$, from this we have that $(\forall x)(x \in B \Rightarrow S(x) \in B)$

But as $10 \in B$ we have that $S(10) \in B$ also, and then $S(S(10)) \in B$ too then $S(S(S(10))) \in B$..., from this I think its possible to "see" that every integer greater than 9 are in $B$ also. But I think its possible to state this in a better way.

For every integer $x$ greater than $9$ which is different from $10$, we have that $(\exists !y)(x = S(y))$, thus if $y \neq 10$, we will have that $(\exists !z)(y = S(z))$ and the same proccess can be repeated until we reach the application of $S$ to $10$, let $z=10$, thus we will have $x = S(S(10))$ which in fact is the integer 12, thus we needed to apply $S$, $x-10$ times to obtain the integer $x$, then if some $x \in P$, we know that applying $S$ in $10$, $x-10$ times will be the same integer, and therefore $x \in B$ because $B$ is closed under $S$, thus $P \subseteq B$.

From this we have that $P=B$ thus (P3) holds true from $(P,S,1)$

**end edit 1**

I dont know what is needed to prove or conclude that the (P3) holds true $(P,S,1)$, in some other exercises its clear that the system dont hold true for (P1) or (P2) and therefore is not a Peano System, but when (P1) and (P2) holds true I dont know how to continue. Thus I need help to understand how (P3) can be proved, I have looked at other questions concerning Peano System and Mathematical Induction axiom, some people says this cannot proved, If it is correct I should just assume (P3) holds true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right, but that's not quite a rigorous proof: phrases like

> the same process can be repeated until we reach the application of $S$ to $10$

are not really precise.

The way to rigorously prove this is ... by induction *in the context of $\mathbb{N}$*, which we presumably already know is a Peano system. Specifically, suppose $B\subseteq P$ contains $10$ and is closed under successor. Let $\hat{B}=B\cup\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

For the first step, can you show that (in the context of $\mathbb{N}$) the set $\hat{B}$ is closed under successor?

> We reason by cases. If $n\in \hat{B}$ and $n+1<10$, then obviously $n+1\in \hat{B}$ since $\hat{B}$ contains everything $<10$. If $n=9$, then $n+1=10$ and we have by assumption that $10\in B$. Finally, if $n\ge 10$ then $n+1\in B$ by assumption on $B$, and so $n+1\in\hat{B}$.

Now what does that tell us about $\hat{B}$?

> We have $1\in\hat{B}$ and $\hat{B}$ is closed under the successor operation; so since $(\mathbb{N},S,1)$ is a Peano system we know $\hat{B}=\mathbb{N}$.

Finally, can you translate this back to $P=\{i\in\mathbb{N}: i\ge 10\}$?

> We have $\hat{B}=\mathbb{N}$, so in particular $P\subseteq \hat{B}$. This is equivalent to $P\cap \hat{B}=P$. On the other hand, we know that $\hat{B}\cap P=B$: the "extra stuff" we added to $B$ to get $\hat{B}$ was all $<10$. Putting these together we get $P=P\cap\hat{B}=B$ as desired.

Comment: Here in  "..then obviously .$n+1 \in \hat{A}..$" should be $n+1 \in \hat{B}..$ ?

If it is just a typo I understood the answer properly. It is very neat, let me ask another "short" question here, when we are proving some system is a Peano System we will always use some other system like $(\mathbb{N}, S, 1)$? I have seen some proof of existence of Peano System in the Mendelson book, but it relies in the existence of Z-inductive set. So when proving something related to the mathematical induction we will always fall direct in some axiom?

and thanks for the awesome answer.

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim Whoops, yeah, that was a typo. Re: proving that something is a Peano system, if you haven't already you'll soon show that any two Peano systems are isomorphic, and conversely anything isomorphic to a Peano system is clearly a Peano system. So the easiest way to show that something is a Peano system is to build an isomorphism between it and your favorite Peano system. (E.g. in this case we could have looked at the map $x\mapsto x-9$; I chose the approach above since it's understandable even if you haven't yet seen isomorphisms.) I'm pretty sure this is always the easiest.

Comment: So in a few words, if $(P,S,1)$ is a Peano System and Im able to define a bijective function $F:P \rightarrow B$, with $B$ closed under $S$, then $(B,S,F(1))$ is a Peano System?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueL.Amorim I'd phrase it a bit more carefully, but that's the idea. Specifically, suppose $(P,S,1)$ is a Peano system, $B$ is a set, $x\in B$, and $T:B\rightarrow B$ is a function. Then $(B,T,x)$ is a Peano system iff there is a bijection $f:P\rightarrow B$ such that $f(1)=x$ and $f(S(a))=T(f(a))$ for all $a\in P$. Moreover, if such an $f$ exists then it is unique. This is a good exercise.

Comment: I noticed these two equality you have show here, is anounced exactly after this exercise about determining if some system is a Peano System, The book put it as an Theorem called Iteration Theorem.

- Consider any Peano System $(P,S,1)$. Let $W$ be an arbitrary set, let $c$ be a fixed element of $W$, and let $g$ be a singulary operation on $W$. Then, there is a unique function $F: P \rightarrow W$ such that

 $$a. F(1) = c$$

 $$b. (\forall x )(x \in P \Rightarrow F(S(x)) = g(F(x)) )$$

I will take some time to study the exercises and look at your answer again before continue.

Comment: I just wonder why the author dont presented this before these exercises, the book is Number Systems and the Foundation of Analysis by Elliot Mendelson.

But the idea is more clear for me now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Im just curious about how it can be done if we are restricted to not use a previously known Peano System (eg: natural numbers), its worth to continue from this question?